# Relate Outlook message inline attachment to element in HTML body

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, javascript-api-for-office

When using Office.js to retrieve the body of an email that has inline attachments, we receive HTML like this:

```
<div>
<div dir="ltr">
<div style="color:black;font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color:white;">
This email has images in the body.</div>
<div style="color:black;font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color:white;">
<img data-imagetype="AttachmentByCid" originalSrc="cid:ab24f213-f1a6-4804-ad70-25a4d3ac5f86" naturalHeight="0" naturalWidth="0" src="cid:ab24f213-f1a6-4804-ad70-25a4d3ac5f86" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" tabindex="-1" size="9026" style="max-width:100%;">
<img data-imagetype="AttachmentByCid" originalSrc="cid:be90d9aa-49a6-48fb-b4b9-d50950aefae3" naturalHeight="0" naturalWidth="0" src="cid:be90d9aa-49a6-48fb-b4b9-d50950aefae3" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" tabindex="-1" size="60886" style="max-width:100%;">
<br>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Where the `<img>` tags are where the inline image attachments would be.

The [attachments property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.1/office.context.mailbox.item?view=outlook-js-1.8#properties) on the mailbox item lists attachment metadata like this:

```
{
attachmentType: "file",
contentType: "image/jpeg",
id: "AAMkADFlM2Q0MzdkLTJhZWQtNGQzNS05YWI2LWMwYmNkZmMwODNmZgBGAAAAAAAbEbu84Nj1SIfOZGQpQsg/BwC74mYLmMGJSYnZmTQHpD7TAAAAAAEJAAC74mYLmMGJSYnZmTQHpD7TAAE1znR7AAABEgAQACz3QOlxzApEvhIoK7iHWoc=",
isInline: true,
name: "home_team.jpg",
size: 9341
}
```

I can't any link between the first image tag and this attachment object. Is there some other way of identifying where each inline attachment is in the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Office.AttachmentDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentdetails?view=outlook-js-preview) interface doesn't provide any property for the content ID value. You need to use EWS to get a property value. See [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) to get started quickly. The [Attachment.ContentId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment.contentid?view=exchange-ews-api) property gets or sets the content identifier of the attachment. `ContentId` can be used as a custom way to identify an attachment in order to reference it from within the body of the item that the attachment belongs to.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the detailed answer. We already had a plan to use EWS to retrieve attachment data for older Outlook clients, so this shouldn't be much additional work. I'll try to remember to post here about how we wen't implementing!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature to get the cid of inline attachments, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: My UV request is here https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/40563703-add-html-identifier-from-message-body-to-inline-at

Comment: Links are obsolete and user-voice does not exist any more.